# What is Helper Class in dart?

Tags: oop, dart

I started learning the dart language. when I heard the term **Helper Class**. I didn't get any clear answer.

Please tell me about

- What is the meaning of the Helper Class?
- For which purpose they are used

Thank you so much to the kind community. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simple words Helper class is like a warehouse where you can put commonly used operations for other classes. So whenever other classes will need them they can access them.

Imagine you have some code which is commonly used in your app. So there are two ways to use that code.

1. To write the same code again and again. (Which no one wants and prefers)
2. To put that code somewhere and call it whenever you need it. And this is a situation where helper class come in to play.

Below are some main objectives behind its creation:

- A helper class is created to make code more readable and clearly organizable.
- They help to eliminate boilerplate code as they contain commonly used functionalities.
- The other goal behind its creation is to provide a common functionality to other classes. In helper class, you can move some methods, variables, and operations, which are commonly used in other classes. So it helps to make your code more organized, maintainable and readable to others.

I hope it helps you. :)